# Add shadow to circular button

Tags: ios, swift

This is the current code I'm using to set the image of one of my buttons. The button is set as an outlet from the storyboard.

```
userPictureButton.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: currentUserData.photoURL), for: .normal)
    userPictureButton.layer.cornerRadius = userPictureButton.frame.size.width / 2
    userPictureButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

Every way to add a shadow to this button seems to fail when `clipsToBounds = true`. When I have clip to bounds off, I can see a shadow but no longer have a circular button.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Embed your `UIButton` in a `UIView` and then apply the `shadow` and `corner radius` according to the below code:

```
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    button.clipsToBounds = true

    containerView.clipsToBounds = false
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

Give the values according to your requirement.